# Check if blender was compiled with openmp

Tags: versions

Is it possible to check if Blender was compiled with OpenMP? How? The installed package is

2.70+git201404250132.3b75d6c-0irie1~trusty1

Comment: This might be a better question for [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: according to [this](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/B/browse/master/SConstruct;f93bc7693a530632455d3ec7acc4bce54a1f85bc$416) it's enabled by default.(scroll down to line 416).

Comment: @maddin45 I looked for build options in the about box.

Comment: @Houssem. But this is from a git repo. They claim it is off in the build bot builds.

Answer (score 6):

In the **Info Editor** go to **Help** and choose **System Info**. Open the internal text editor and select the created file: system-info.txt. Under build flags look for -fopenmp.

[image]
[image]

Note that the build flags depend on your system. For gcc -fopenmp is needed to compile with openmp support.

Answer (score 6):

Probably the easiest way is to use the Python console and enter `getattr(bpy.app.build_options, 'openmp')`

[image]